# What am I doing wrong ? I am getting this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: image is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create super mario with javascript but I am getting an error.
I don't understand why I am getting this error please help me out.
I wasn't getting this error before I added a class and const sprite.
I think it has something to do with the const sprite and class SpriteSheet.
I have attached screen shot of that error and I have also entered the whole code.

```js
// A Function That loads image
function loadImage(url){ // give pram of url
    return new Promise(resolve => { // create a promise
        const image =  new Image(); // set image to IMAGE() function
        image.addEventListener('load', () => { // add eventlistener to load that image
            resolve(image); // resolve image
        });
        image.src= url; // use param and src to enter url
    });
}
// Class SpriteSheet

class SpriteSheet{
    constructor(image, width, height){
        this.image = image;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.tiles = new Map();
    }
    // define a buffer so we don't have to create same element again and again.
    define(name,x,y){
        const buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
        buffer.width = this.width;
        buffer.heigth = this.height;
        buffer.getContext('2d').drawImage(
            this.image,
            x * this.height,
            y * this.width, 
            this.height,
            this.width,
            0,
            0,
            this.width,
            this.height);
            this.tiles.set(name,buffer);
    }
    draw(name, x, y){
        const buffer = this.tiles.get(name);
        context.drawImage(buffer,x,y);
    };
}

// Draw a Canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById('screen'); 
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create a Rectange
context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

// Define

const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
sprites.define('ground', 0,0);
sprites.draw('ground', context, 45,62);
// Load Image
loadImage('/img/tiles.png')
.then(image => {
    context.drawImage(image,0,0,16,16,0,0,16,16); // (img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height) // First Four means subset you want to draw and other four means where you want to draw it
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Super Mario</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="\js\main.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="screen" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `image` hasn't been defined on the top level at the time you call `const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);`

Comment: Seems you should move your _sprites_ code into the `then` callback so it runs after `loadImage()` resolves with the `HTMLImageElement`

Comment: @Phil it worked thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

A promise takes two arguments: resolve and reject.

```
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(image));
    image.addEventListener('error', () => reject(image));
    image.src = url;
  });
}
```

Comment: While this is generally good advice, I don't think it's particularly relevant to OP's issue